# Android: NetworkInterface is immutable?

Tags: java, android, wifi, ip-address, android-wifi

I've run across a strange issue with NetworkInterface object.

I obtain it as NetworkInterface.getByName("wlan0") and it all seems to work well.

But as soon as the WiFi network switches to another one, it gets unexpected (at least to me):

1. The getInetAddresses() method keeps returning old IP address.
2. The NetworkInterface.getByName("wlan0") method returns **new** NetworkInterface object which has proper IP address!

I.e. right after the WiFi network switchover I can have two different NetworkInterface objects having same name (getName()) and different IP addresses returned.

Is this something by design?  I listen to WiFi Manager's events; should this object be re-acquired every time... SUPPLICANT_CONECTION_CHANGE_ACTION or something else?

Comment: what for you are using networkinterface? post your code

Comment: @kEN, I use that to retrieve WiFi IP address.  My code is in the big system scattered across; no small tidy piece, sorry.